# solaris 10 code below works fine, but is nothing is ever generated via cron

Tags: cron, solaris

root crontab

```
20 * * * * [ "$(ls -A /var/spool/lp/requests/localhost/)" ] && echo "lp queue not empty " || echo "lp queue empty" | /usr/ucb/mail foobar@foobar.com 2>&1
```

Codes above works fine, but is nothing is ever generated via cron?

Ideas?

Comment: "works fine" seems to be a stretch if it doesn't work.

Comment: command line (bash) it is fine, in cron nothing happens

Comment: ah wait, on solaris 10, what is the shell that cron uses?

Comment: sh, i added SHELL=/bin/bash before the ~~gobblygok~~ messy test,  still nothing

Comment: My suggestion, first move the whole command line into a single script. Then manually run it with Solaris default shell for cron and, only if that single script works, go back to cron.

Comment: You _might_ be able to put that all into a string and use `bash -c`...

Comment: What is the intended logic here? As written, doesn't your pipeline only send mail if the test fails?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.